# Codeigniter file upload - possible to use callbacks? (v2)

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, frameworks, upload

Is it possible using the Codeigniter framework to put in some form of callback that will check to see if an uploaded file exists, if so give javascript confirm alert stating 'overwrite'.

If they click 'Ok' - it will overwrite the file, if 'Cancel' it will append a number to the file (and not overwrite the existing file).

Essentially the config['overwrite'] below would have to be called after the user clicks ok/cancel on the confirmation alert - is this possible?

```
$config['overwrite']    = FALSE;        
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Comment: I have done form validation on 'file upload' field before. So yes, it can be done. But if your question is 'how', I'm sorry I cant answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create a controller/method that does the checking,

create a simple button with javascript (not type="submit", because you are gonna trigger the form.submit() manually) you send the file name via ajax to your controller/method, and show a confirmation box in the client side according to the response you get, if he clicks ok cancel, you add an 'overwrite' parameter to the form (via javascript) then submit it.

The solution I'm providing here is based on my understanding of what you have explained, I didn't really get the point of appending a number to the file when he clicks cancel, but if you explain more you may get a better answer,

good luck.